# BeautifulSoup: get elements that have a certain attribute, independent of its value

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Imagine I have the following html:

```
<div id='0'>
    stuff here
</div>

<div id='1'>
    stuff here
</div>

<div id='2'>
    stuff here
</div>

<div id='3'>
    stuff here
</div>
```

Is there a simple way to extract all `div`'s that have the attribute `id`, independent of its value using BeautifulSoup? I realize it is trivial to do this with xpath, but it seems that there's no way to do xpath search in BeautifulSoup.

Comment: The official docs look pretty good to me: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `id=True` to match only elements that have the attribute set:

```
soup.find_all('div', id=True)
```

The inverse works too; you can *exclude* tags with the `id` attribute:

```
soup.find_all('div', id=False):
```

To find tags with a given attribute you can also use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('div[id]'):
```

but this does not support the operators needed to search for the inverse, unfortunately.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = '''\
... <div id="id1">This has an id</div>
... <div>This has none</div>
... <div id="id2">This one has an id too</div>
... <div>But this one has no clue (or id)</div>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> soup.find_all('div', id=True)
[<div id="id1">This has an id</div>, <div id="id2">This one has an id too</div>]
>>> soup.find_all('div', id=False)
[<div>This has none</div>, <div>But this one has no clue (or id)</div>]
>>> soup.select('div[id]')
[<div id="id1">This has an id</div>, <div id="id2">This one has an id too</div>]
```

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup4 supports [commonly-used css selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

```
>>> import bs4
>>>
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('''
... <div id="0"> this </div>
... <div> not this </div>
... <div id="2"> this too </div>
... ''')
>>> soup.select('div[id]')
[<div id="0"> this </div>, <div id="2"> this too </div>]
```